# How to Send Mail from JavaMail via Localhost

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am creating a form, which will send out the details via email upon user completes his details and click submit.

Mail Submission with JavaMail:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String host = "localhost";
        String from = "root@localhost.localdomain";

        try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        Address fromAddress = new InternetAddress("root@localhost.localdomain");

        message.setFrom(fromAddress);

        InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress("sendToAliases@localhost.localdomain");
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);

        message.setSubject("Email Details Sending");
        message.setText("This is my testing content.");

        transport.connect(host, from);
        message.saveChanges();
        Transport.send(message);
        transport.close();
    } finally { 
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I am using Email aliases for sendToAliases@localhost.localdomain which means I could have 4 email aliases from sendToAliases. However, I am unable to reach any emails upon deploying and running the above mail file. Can anyone please advise me?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, i just did a telnet myserver 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Have you checked the log files?
- Do you get any exceptions or errors when running the program?
- Do you have a [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) server running in localhost?
- Is the SMTP server accepting connections from localhost?
- Can you send emails via that server using normal email client and receive them somehow?
- Try to make your program a standalone commandline program and try to execute it

You seem to have a missing quote in `message.setSubject("Email Details Sending);`. Are you sure that your servlet actually compiles?

Comment: Hi,

I tested that sending emails from the commandline using telnet, it works out perfectly. Regarding the message.setSubject("Email Details Sending); is a typo due to pasting. I have that in the code. Compilation is fine.

Comment: @jl.can u share some tutorial for smtp runing in localhost windows for java thanks!